# Payment Gateway in Webview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, payment

Does apple/google store reject if payments are handled from web view?

This means without using any mobile SDK open an in-app web view and complete the payment.

Answer (score 1):

*It doesn't Matter you are using Payment Gateway through webView or mobile SDK
Apple have Policy That you can use Third Parties Payment Gateway for Physical goods like E-Commerce Applications and Delivery application Payment gateway but For Digital Content like Movies Musics or For Subscription base Application you have to use apple In-app Purchase otherwise apple will reject your Application. and You cant use In-app Purchase in Webview you need to develop applications properly with Swift Langauge or if you are using Cross-platform Flutter and React-native.*

[Guideline 3.1.1 - In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Comment: Ok, the product is a digital photo so I assume it will require SDK integration instead of a web view. Thanks

Comment: if your product is a digital photo so you need Apple In-App Purchase Third-Parties Payment does not work for digital Products.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try with webview for payment gateway , store does not reject it, please read the New Policy of Google play before use it for any restriction for this process...if no restriction then you can proceed.....hope it may help you

Comment: Even in the case of a digital in-app product like a digital photo web view can be used? Are you certain?

Comment: Yes can be use for digital in-app product